# How to get the attribute value in the ValidationEventHandler in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I'm trying to unmarshal the xml file using JAXB. Before it starts parsing,first it will validate the xml file.

I'm using the Custom Validation EventHandler to catch the events and print the list of errors in a **errors.xml** file.

I'm trying to print the attribute value along with the error Message in the errors.xml file . I'm able to get the error Message in the event,but I'm unable to get the attribute value in the event.

How can I get the attribute value for the specific event ?

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

```
My code:

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.piyush");
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(new File("D:/liferay-develop/workspace/cat_test/v1/STD_MP.xsd")));
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    jaxbUnmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
    ValidationEventCollector validationCollector= new ValidationEventCollector();
    jaxbUnmarshaller.setEventHandler( validationCollector );
    STDMP ts = (STDMP)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xml_gkuzu);
    if(validationCollector.hasEvents())
    {
        for(ValidationEvent event:validationCollector.getEvents())
        {
            String msg = event.getMessage();
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
```

Comment: Can anyone please suggest me regatding this issue ?